# TreeView Items dump pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

how can dump alls items of  TreeView

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path = PathApp, class_name='TreeView')

image
https://ibb.co/WfQMyFQ

Answer (score 0):

There is method `.dump_tree()` for top window specification.

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path = PathApp, class_name='TreeView')
app.window(title="somesoft").dump_tree()
```